# Delphi XE4 TeeChart Pro 2013 installs correctly but I get "Class not found" when open units in project

Tags: delphi, vcl, teechart, delphi-xe4

I have a project with a unit that includes VCLTee.TeeComma in its uses clause an declares an object of class TeeCommander. When I open the unit I get the error: "Class TTeeCommander not found."

The same thing happens with a unit that includes VCLTee.Chart.TeeChart with the error "Class TChart not found."

I believe that the installer for TeeChart Pro 2013 worked correctly. Moreover, I have included the path to the required .dcu files in my Tools > Options > Delphi Options > Library and I can see that VCLTee.TeeComma.dcu and VCLTee.Chart.TeeChart.dcu are in that path.

Moreover, the namespace and scoping appears correct as far as I can tell.

Why might the IDE have trouble finding these files?

Interestingly, I don't find any of the "Tee" components on my Tool Palette. Maybe this is because the package was not installed with the "Install Packages" option in the IDE. I thought that running the .exe installer should have been enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At design time the implementations for the classes of a third party library are provided in a design time package. So, if your IDE cannot find the classes then the Teechart design time packages must be missing from the IDE.

I can't say why they are missing, and which ones you need to add to the IDE. From memory I think that you can add them from the Component | Install Packages menu.

Perhaps the best solution would be to uninstall Teechart, and go through the installation process again.

Comment: Interestingly, none of the .bpl files are listed under the project > options > packages. I thought they should be, but wondered if I should be installing packages manually when the product comes with an installer.

Comment: After adding some .bpl files to the project packages list from the default Steema directory under Delphi18.win32\Bin I was able to get rid of the error, "Class TChart not found." In the process of trying to get rid of other errors, rather than uninstalling and reinstalling, I ran the TeeRecompile.exe program, which seems to have chosen a different set of .bpl files to install, but still clears up the problem with TChart.

Comment: So, is your question answered?

Comment: Yes. My question is answered. Somehow reinstalling TeeChart Pro did not help with the error, but running TeeRecompile.exe did.